# How big is too big?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 60mb excel file that has all of the "sins"... Array formulas, VBA and conditional formats. It crashes all the time and it's now being suggested that it's too big. There are about 20 worksheets and 3 of them are 15mb in size and each have about 35,000,000 active cells. Is this why the sheet crashes?

Comment: Yes this is why, also calling VBA functions from sheets helps crashing a lot.

Comment: Any shots at a remedy?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Data-Model-specification-and-limits-19aa79f8-e6e8-45a8-9be2-b58778fd68ef

Comment: Nope. Try splitting it into several separate files, other than that, nope.

Comment: It's great to see this but it definitely suggests that I am no where near maximum file size. I have a 64-bit office 365 version.

Comment: One tip, is if your data is all in a table or such, is to copy/paste as values all rows, except the "top" row.  I.E. If your range is A1:ZZ1000, and each column uses the same formula, you can copy row 2 on down, then paste as values.  This will keep your formulas if you need to re-run it, but also reduce a lot of heavy lifting.  It may not get it to a nice, manageable size, but it may help.  Also of course, consider if you really need all those conditional formats, etc.

Comment: I once tried an experiment with a large sheet and removed all of the conditional formats to see if it mattered. No difference. The paste values option cannot apply here because the reports are dynamic.

Comment: I tried splitting the workbook. It was worse. 35,000,000 cells referencing data in another workbook was nightmarish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's not inappropriate to post this. 
After some stalling and perhaps some skepticism, I replaced all of the array formulas in my sheet. There were approximately 1,500,000 cells affected by array formulas and I didn't relish the thought of redoing this.  BUT WHAT AN UNBELIEVABLE DIFFERENCE!  The sheet now runs faster, better and very reliably!  I'll never use an array formula again. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Yea I have this problem also.

This is a compilation of hat works for me. Some of this may be relevant, some may not.

1. Turn off automatic calculation. If you are desperate about this, then turn it off while doing the rest of the list but turn on afterwards
2. Make a backup. Everytime something on this list works, make a new backup. Excel has no brain, make sure to use your own.
3. Remove empty-but-not-empty cells... Sometimes, for a number of reasons, excel finds it necessary to keep track of *all* possible rows and columns.
   I fix this by recreating whatever chart I have made by copying the specific areas that are needed on new sheets and then delete the old one and rename the new one to match. Search/replace will fix formulas afterwards if they get buggered. You can also mark the rows/cols and right-click -> delete rows/cols but that may cause a total freeze so I prefer the former method.
4. Get rid of the array formulas. Seriously, they can in 90-something % of the time be replaced by a cleverer sumproduct, sumifs or index(match()) formula or by adding columns or doing things in 2 steps. They are resource hogs. Leftovers from a different age. The only time I accept arrays is when I know I have exhausted all possibilities.
5. Very important, save the files as x64 binary formats for the files **(.xlsb)**. Do not use the "compatibility" format **(.xlsx)** and for the love of god, do not use regular **.xls**
6. Move all graphics to separate sheets, and better yet, separate files. Mirror the result data via vba, copy paste, whatever to separate files and have your conditional formatting, images, graphs, progress bars, gantts, whatever there.